# What's the proper way to schedule tasks and reminders in Oreo?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

#### Background

Ever since Android O came out I had trouble with what classes and methods I should use when I want to schedule background sync tasks and notifications, more specifically, I want to do these two **separate** things:

- Background sync task to download data from the server, and notify the user about important information (that was just fetched from the server). These syncs should occur at an almost precise time of the day (e.g. 21:30 ±10min).
- Notify the user about an upcoming event, for example, one week before an exam.

Because Android O has placed some restrictions on [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), I cannot set a background service that runs at a specific time of the day, unless I use `getForegroundService()`, which, as the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) say, should only be used for services that are noticeable to the user.

#### What I tried / considered

I have been using JobService that runs periodically every so and so hours, but I would prefer for it to run at a more specific time of the day.

I have looked into [CalendarProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), and also considered a push notification service, but it seems to me like an overkill for simple tasks like these.

#### Question

My final question is what methods I could, or I should use to implement the above features?

Answer (score 1):

**Use WorkManager** this is the best way to Run Task in Background in **Android Oreo and Pie versions** **and it also works in older versions of Android.**

**See the Documentation**

1. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager
2. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics
3. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced

**GitHub Example**

1. https://github.com/krunalpatel3/WorkManager-Example-Andorid

**Reference**

- http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-use-workmanager-in-android/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAQKvBHeg_w
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VVir3-4hII
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jgkQYebYvQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooP8kkhvRQI

Comment: Haven't noticed that before. Yet I can't see any mention of setting the work at a specific time, only at a periodic interval, so it doesn't answer all of my requirements.

Comment: so you want to run task in background at particular time ones.